# JS keycode event

Tags: javascript, html, события

пытаюсь сделать html страницу с

> event.keyCode

написал такой скрипт :

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', eventT, false);

    function eventT(event) {

        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                console.log('вперед');
                break;
            case 40:
                console.log('назад');
                break;
            case 37:
                console.log('лево');
                break;
            case 39:
                console.log('право');
                break;
        }
    }
```

здесь все работает но как можно сделать движение нискосоком добавил такой скрипт но не сработало

```
if (event.keyCode == 37 && event.keyCode == 38) {
      console.log('найскосок NUM7')
} else
if (event.keyCode == 38 && event.keyCode == 39) {
      console.log('найскосок NUM9')
}
```

и столкнулся с еще одной проблемой когда нажимаешь стрелку верх и на стрелку налево стрелка верх прерывается можно ли этого избежать?

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Control Panel</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Control Panel</H1>
<br/>
<br/>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('keydown', eventT, false);
    function eventT(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37 && event.keyCode == 38) {
            console.log('найскосок NUM7')
            document.addEventListener('keydown', eventT, false);
        } else
        if (event.keyCode == 38 && event.keyCode == 39) {
            console.log('найскосок NUM9')
        }
        console.log(event.keyCode)
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                console.log('вперед');
                document.addEventListener('keydown', eventT, false);
                break;
            case 40:
                console.log('назад');
                document.addEventListener('keydown', eventT, false);
                break;
            case 37:
                console.log('лево');
                document.addEventListener('keydown', eventT, false);
                break;
            case 39:
                console.log('право');

                break;
        }
    }
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы обрабатывать одновременное нажатие клавиш, надо нажатия записывать отдельно, а обрабатывать - отдельно. Попробуйте:

```js
const keys = [];
document.onkeydown = e => {
    if(keys.indexOf(e.which)<0) keys.push(e.which);
};
document.onkeyup = e => {
    keys.splice(keys.indexOf(e.which),1);
};

setInterval(() => {
  keys.forEach(item => {
      switch(item){
          case 87:case 38://W
            console.log('вперед');
          break;
          case 68:case 39://D
            console.log('вправо');
          break;
          case 65:case 37://A
            console.log('влево');
          break;
          case 83:case 40://S
            console.log('назад');
          break;
          default:
          //console.log(item);
      }
  });
  // Наискосоки:

    if (keys.includes(37) && keys.includes(38)) {
        console.log('найскосок NUM7')
    } 
    if (keys.includes(38) && keys.includes(39)) {
        console.log('найскосок NUM9')
    }
    if (keys.includes(39) && keys.includes(40)) {
        console.log('найскосок NUM3')
    }
    if (keys.includes(37) && keys.includes(40)) {
        console.log('найскосок NUM1')
    }
}, 111);
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вы заморочились... Вот что-то похожее на более правильную реализацию:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', eventT, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', eventT, false);
var arrowLeft=false;
var arrowRigth = false;
var arrowForward = false;
var arrowBack = false;
    function eventT(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                arrowForward = !arrowForward;
                break;
            case 40:
                arrowBack = !arrowBack;
                break;
            case 37:
                arrowLeft = !arrowLeft;
                break;
            case 39:
                arrowRigth = !arrowRigth;
                break;
        }

        if(arrowRigth === true)
        {
            if(arrowForward === true)
                console.log('диагональ направо');
            else
                console.log('право');
        }
        else if(arrowLeft === true)
        {
            if(arrowForward === true)
                console.log('диагональ налево');
            else
                console.log('лево');
        }
        else if (arrowBack === true)
        {
          console.log('назад');
        }
        else if(arrowForward === true)
        {
          console.log('вперед');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Плохо работает. нажал вверх - пишет вверх. окей. нажал влево - пишет влево.. (должна быть диагональ). отпустил вверх - началась диагональ) должно быть влево

Comment: Стоп, я не понял. Вам надо по очереди, что-бы кнопки нажимались?

Comment: Все нормально работает: https://jsfiddle.net/bt4ga1tm/16/  
Другое дело, что нужно ввести задержку для проверки, что-бы фильтровать не одновременное нажатие кнопок и добавить больше состояний...

Comment: Нажимаем - вправо, потом вперёд, потом влево, потом отпускаем вправо, потом отпускаем вперёд - и в консоли у нас диагональ вправо, а зажата кнопка влево... Это НЕ нормально)

Comment: А, теперь понял :)